# Threads or state machine to manage application state?

Tags: design-patterns, state, state-machine

I have a web application that automatically configures a device. Communication is achieved in a request - response fashion using HTTP. I am currently using a thread to manage the configuration procedure but it is generally recommended that application threads are not spawned in web servers so my question is should I be using a event based mechanism rather than a thread? are event framework's used to maintain application state or am I thinking about them in the wrong way?

If there are any more applicable design patterns, I'd love to hear about them.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A state machine is a design pattern, while a thread is an implementation choice. Do you mind clarifying your question a bit more ?

Comment: @Prashant Is a design pattern not also an implementation choice? This is exactly my question, is there a better way to maintain the state of the application configuration procedure rather than using an additional thread?

Comment: I meant that you can implement a state machine inside a thread. I would guess that what you are asking is if you should use a event based model versus threads, but that's just a guess. Sorry, not an answer, but the question confuses me.

Comment: Yes your right, I mean some kind of event based model. I guess the question is confusing because I'm pretty confused myself..

Comment: ok. got it. I've suggested and edit to reflect this. The next question is 1) why you think threads should not be spawned in web servers and 2) Is your model like this - web app runs on a device to configure it, the configuration is downloaded from a web server and the web server is spawning threads to handle individual requests from web app clients.

Comment: There are a number of reasons why it is recommended that threads are not spawned from servlets, see http://old.nabble.com/Can-servlets-safely-spawn-threads--to8687142.html from some reasons. Yes my model is similar to what you stated. Its not as simple though, I have a number of different types or requests outside of the standard download. For example, SetParameter, GetParameter etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I am fully understanding your situation, here, but I'll have a stab at it anyway.

Years ago I designed an application for the servicing of ADSL activation requests for a large Telco operator in my country.

We received "activation requests" from an upstream application, and our job was to operate a series of configuration steps which had to be done on different devices, using different protocols, could fail, might have to be retracted (and of course, implement the cancellation of one or more steps in case the customer receded).

We opted for a solution based on a "state machine" of sort. Each request was represented (in an Oracle DB) as a header record which summarized the status (from "new" to "completed", with various intermediate steps) and a series of child records, each one representing one of the N-steps required to complete the configuration.

We had scheduled batches for each kind of step, basically selecting the records of the appropriate operation-type, and attempting to resolve each one (this allowed us to group the operation according to protocol, e.g. snmp or telnet, and also to define that some kind of operations should run only during night, or outside of peak office hours and so on.

We also scheduled a "meta-batch" which would periodically check every open "header" record, check if all the connected step-records were in "finished" state, and update the header status accordingly.

It scaled well enough, and allowed us to model different steps with a minimum of hassle. Full or partial "rollback" was easy, too - because for each step we had a concrete record showing if it had completed or not.

If I had to work on a similar problem today, I'd favour a state-machine based approach.

Comment: What you described is exactly what I need to do. However, I am only using one protocol, TR-069. I get an activation request or "Inform" and then I need to carry out configuration. When you say that you would favor a state-machine based approach; are you talking about the database state machine you implemented or one that does not specifically store its state in a database?

Comment: Some kind of persistence (be it a "traditional" DB or something else) would surely be handy, don't you think? I fact, my original design started as a prototype using just flat files to hold the status, when we reached 80k devices we switched to Oracle (I tried all the tricks I knew, but it was already getting glacially slow before moving to a DB...). Anyway, I'd go for a state machine of sort, so that the various actions can be handled in the most efficient way possible, and you can easily understand what went wrong if one step fails.

Comment: I am storing all the data from the device in a database but I am not storing "state" specific data. Every time the device starts a new session with the server the configuration procedure is run. If you were to store state headers in a DB would this mean that inconsistencies could arise for example someone ssh's to a device and changes something and the server does not know about it. How did you determine if the state headers were still valid for a device?

Comment: First of all, the whole idea behind the application was to automate a complicated setup of thousands of devices. Plus we had some rudimental "probing" services to see if a given device was faulty or not. On top of that, most of the configuration steps were designed so that in case things were in an inconsistent state we would get some error from the device (as the result of our configuration attempt) and therefore the step was moved to a special "ERR" state, so that human intervention could sort these out.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Prashant that trying to compare the State-Machine pattern with threading is apples and oranges. How do you currently configure the device withing the thread?  What are the long-term requirements for tracking the state of the device and will the state of the device change over time?

In other words, is the configuration a one-shot effort in which it was convienent to push off onto a separate thread?  If you care about the transitions, especially over a relatively long period of time, for a CPU, the State-Machine pattern is a tool to help you model the different states and the possible transitions.

You can implement a state-machine many ways. For example you can use events to trigger transitions while some static variable tracks the current state.  You could do it in a separate thread which has a big loop with a large switch statement inside of it.

I would ask two questions:

1) How have you modeled the state of your device?

2) Does the thread buy you anything specific towards configuring the device?

Comment: First, Create a configuration thread, this thread contains the config procedure which contains a number of different commands to execute on the device. Each command is sent to the device by passing it to a servlet which is waiting for a message to pass back to the device (the device initiates the connection). When the device receives a command it always replies with a command response. The servlet passes this response to the configuration thread which then continues with the configuration. The only reason I am using a thread is to maintain the position and state of the configuration procedure.

Comment: The whole passing a message between two threads and all the complexity's of having multiple threads makes me want to simplify this to a single thread.